# 13F Security List

Tags: sec

I am looking for an API to download the list of securities that will need to be in the 13F filings from asset managers. Does the SEC have such an API or a non-PDF file that can help with getting the data electronically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This website](http://13f-excel.com/) periodically uploads the 13F securities list as an Excel workbook.
Also, Bloomberg's FLDS function has a field for you to check whether a security is in the 13F.